# Schedule a task to run only once

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks, java-ee-6

I'm working on a recovery monitor which waits for 5 minutes and fires an alert if system has not been recovered yet. The monitor needs to be started at start up and to fire alert only once. The source code looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class RecoveryMonitor {
    @Inject TimerService timerService;
    @Inject MyAlertService alertService;
    @Inject SystemRecovery systemRecovery;

    public void scheduleMonitor() {
        timerService.createSingleActionTimer(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5),
            new TimerConfig);
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout() {
        if (!systemRecovery.isDone) {
            alertService.alert("System recovery failed");
        }
    }
}
```

So, the problem here is how to schedule a task, i.e. invoke scheduleMonitor method. I cannot use @PostConstruct as it's not allowed to. I think about using @Schedule, but it executes a method periodically while I only to do it once. Any solutions and/or suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

L

**UPDATE**: by making the class not Stateless anymore, e.g. make it a @Singleton, I am able to start scheduling using @PostConstruct. This is not a complete solution but it works for me:

```
@Singleton
public class RecoveryMonitor {
    @Inject TimerService timerService;
    @Inject MyAlertService alertService;
    @Inject SystemRecovery systemRecovery;

    @PostConstruct
    public void scheduleMonitor() {
        timerService.createSingleActionTimer(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5),
            new TimerConfig);
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout() {
        if (!systemRecovery.isDone) {
            alertService.alert("System recovery failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could annotate the `@Singleton` bean with `@Startup` to obtain eager initialization at container startup.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Servlet Environment you could fire a CDI Event(e.g. ApplicationStartedEvent) within a ServletContextListener and observe that event in your EJB. This kind of startup logic has to be done manually in CDI 1.0. Future versions will probably contain something similar.

If you have questions on how to do that, just ask :)